# Stuart (came-reached-arrived-turned )second in the swimming competition

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, difference

What is the correct choice , arrive and reach used to talk about a place only , example:stuart arrived in France, turned is used when an age has passed ,example he turned 15 , that all I know

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Only _came_ is possible out of your list. There is also _was placed second_ (the dictionary says it's a British usage).

Comment: @KateBunting I think 'reached second' is OK too, but it makes it sound like it was an uphill battle. You can also have 'won second,' 'got second' or 'finished second.' And in Britain we can say 'Stuart placed second' as well as 'Stuart was placed second,' they both make sense.

Comment: The one that makes the least sense is 'turned second.' Don't ever say that.

Comment: Confusingly, 'turned second' *does* make sense (and is standard usage) in the context of a single swimming race with multiple lengths, with a 'turn' at the end of each length. If a competitor was the second to reach the half-way point in a two-length race, we would say they 'turned second'. But I doubt that is what is intended here.

Answer (score 1):

In races, here are some colloquial ways to say this:

- He **came in** second
- He **came in** in second place
- He placed second
- He got second place
- He came second
- He finished second
- He won second place

There are probably others; please feel free to add them.